# child process is of 4 kb size more than the parent process?

Tags: fork

If I use fork() system call to create a child process then I use #ps aux command to see the size of the processes, I always see that the child process is of 4 KB more than the parent one!!!
I also want to know how can I know the actual address of any process in RAM not the relative shown in /proc/pid/maps
Thanks in advance

```
pid = fork();
if( pid == 0)
{
    getchar();
    execlp("/usr/bin/top", NULL);
}
else
{
    wait(&childstatus);
    printf("Hello From Parent\n");
}
```

I run #ps aux when the child process is waiting for getchar().

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question, such as showing some code you are running. Why are you worried about the extra 4KB? Are you running a proccess on a microcontroller with limited memory?

Comment: I am not worried about the size. I just want to understand what actually is happening in the background. I know when I use fork(), the child process shares the address space of the parent process. If the child change anything (like a variable) then copy on write happens and the child process will have its own copy of that variable. Now as far as the two process shares the address space initially, why they do not have the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel employs copy-on-write methods while copying memory from parent's process address space to child's one.

Another thing is that kernel will add about 2kB (on 32-bit system) descriptor to process table on `fork`.

> I also want to know how can I know the actual address of any process in RAM not the relative shown in /proc/pid/maps

Well, this will require some kind of kernel debugger. There was some [kdb or kgdb](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/) as far as I remember.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as far as I know "copy on write" happens only when the child tries to write something. That is why it is called as "copy on write"

Comment: why this 2 kb extra? For what it is used? and why I have 4 kb difference not only 2 kb?

Comment: 2 or 4 kB depends on architecture. It is used to describe running process in process table (a list to be precise). I'd recommend you to take a look at Robert's Love book named 'Linux Kernel Development' on chapter 'Process Management'

Comment: But this is a common thing that the both processes need to have not only the child. My question is why the child process has more 4 kb than the parent one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that this 4 KB extra is because of wait(). If I remove it, both parent and child processes will be of the same size.
But can anyone tell me why does wait() consume more 4 KB extra?